# Do all search bots use escaped fragment?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, facebook, seo

I've built an Angular SPA. Some of my `head` code looks like this:

```
<!--title-->
<title ng-bind="$root.title"></title>

<!--web-->
<meta name="application-name" content="{{$root.site.name}}">
<meta name="description" content="{{$root.page.description}}">

<!--facebook-->
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="{{$root.page.title}}">
<meta property="og:url" content="{{$root.site.url}}">
<meta property="og:image" content="{{$root.site.url}}/framework/img/brand/facebook.jpg">
<meta property="og:description" content="{{$root.page.description}}">

<!--twitter-->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="{{$root.page.title}}">
<meta name="twitter:url" content="{{$root.site.url}}">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="{{$root.site.url}}/framework/img/brand/social.jpg">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="{{$root.page.description}}">

<!--routing-->
<base href="/">
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

For the purpose of SEO I've set my app to recognise requests with the escaped fragment `?_escaped_fragment_=`. When these requests come through, it serves a prerendered version of the page.

Does every search bot use the escaped fragment? For example, if I post a link to a page of my SPA on Facebook, will it fetch the prerendered version of the page, or the unrendered version?

Facebook should hopefully go to the page, see the fragment meta tag and understand it's an ajax application, then revisit the page with the escaped fragment to receive prerendered content.

Comment: No. Not yet. At least not that is confirmed.

Comment: @JohnConde so Facebook would just go to `www.example.com/something` rather than `www.example.com/?escaped_fragment_=/something` and therefore only get the curly brackets in my meta tags rather than the actual content?

Comment: If they don't support escaped fragments, yes

Comment: Oh dear. Is there an alternative solution to binding meta data to SPA views?

Comment: put nginx infront and redirect to prerender for bots.

Comment: @YOU I'm already doing that. I detect for bots using the escaped fragment string in the URL and redirect them to prerendered content. My question is do all search bots use the escaped fragment? I know Google does but not sure about Facebook, Twitter etc.

Comment: @JohnConde I've done more research and posted an answer to my own question. You are partially right but I think you may find out something new from the links I posted.

Comment: I supposed to say that you can do without using escaped fragment with nginx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like support for the Crawlable Ajax Spec is patchy. Some search bots support it, some don't.

> - Google: Yes
> - Bing: Yes
> - Yandex: Yes
> - Facebook (open graph reading bot): Only for hashbang URLs
> - Twitter Cards bot: No
> - Google+ bot: Yes
> - LinkedIn bot: No

(The above was summarised in a comment by Robert Dunne here: http://builtvisible.com/javascript-framework-seo/)

A more detailed post explaining this can be found here:

http://blog.ajaxsnapshots.com/2013/11/googles-crawlable-ajax-specification.html

Fortunately, there are ways to detect the search bots that don't support CAS and force the `?escaped_fragment_=` into the url to direct them to snapshot (prerendered) pages with the meta tags filled with the content!

A description of various configurations to do this can be found here:
https://ajaxsnapshots.com/configGuide

Comment: Is this still true ? Does more services need this ? This is important knowing that now Google doesn't need it anymore http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.fr/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

Comment: @Ciseur check http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86262/should-we-drop-ajax-crawling-scheme (spoiler: yes)

Comment: Thanks Mario, this needed to be said here.

Comment: Google does indeed apparently execute all javascript on pages now, but it's difficult to tell how well it does this and how long it will wait for the content to load. You also need to bear in mind that many other search engines are not this advanced yet. So in conclusion, yes I would recommend you prerender content and serve that to search engines.